# Ordering orders collection by newest

Tags: magento-1.8, export

How can I sort orders by newest? Currently I'm filtering by `complete` and `canceled` status and I want to sort results by latest ordered date or by latest order ID. Now it show to me by the first ID lets say `10000001` but i want it to be 1000010

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()                            
    ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('nin' => array('canceled','complete')))                       
    ->addFieldToFilter('state',Array('eq'=>Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW))                        
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the `addAttributeToSort()` method:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('nin' => array('canceled', 'complete')))
    ->addFieldToFilter('state', array('eq' => Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW))
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToSort('increment_id', 'DESC')
;

foreach ($collection as $item) {
    echo $item->getIncrementId();
}
```

You can edit the attribute (and direction) on which the collection has to be sorted on.